# deployed ASP.NET web applicaton tries to read the reference from my local computer

Tags: asp.net, excel, class, com

I built a web application that inserts value to an excel file and deployed in on an Internet server. When I try to run it I realize that the application try to read Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference from my local PC instead of server

I am getting the following error

> Exception Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-0000...

... Application tries to reach my local PC

```
C:\Users\****\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\
```

Did I do something wrong when I deployed my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` requires that Excel is installed on the server.
   Dlls in bin are not enough, since COM system is used to invoke an existing application.
   You have to install Excel on the server
2. Browsing DCOM you have to find CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-0000...
3. Your application (ASP.NET) must be authorized on the server to access DCOM library. [This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1303594.aspx/1) shows how to configure permission.

Comment: Yes I installed the same version of Excel on the Server,too.

Comment: Ok; browsing COM components on the server, can you find one called 00024500-0000-0000-C000-0000..  ?

Comment: Yes, I found it as a registry entry referred to Microsoft Excel Application.

Comment: So, try step 3 of my answer: could be an authorization problem

Comment: Thank you very much. it solved my problem but stil it looks like the application tries to  write excel files to my local PC instead of server even though the application is deployed on the server.